# Using REST calls to match range of local objects to server objects

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, rest, client

I am connected to an exchange and using REST calls I need to keep a local state syncronized to what is happening on the exchange. Specifically I need to keep updated information about the state of active orders and current position. New orders are sometimes sent to the exchange and existing orders are sometimes removed, and I need confirmation of when these updates I have performed actually have gone through. Sometimes an active order is partially or completely executed, and then I need information about the volume executed (to update current position) and a confirmation the the order is not active anymore or that it's still active but with less volume. To receive information from the exchange, I can perform two types of REST calls:

- Get transactions. Parameters: How many of the last transactions to be returned. Returns the following information on a specifiec number of last transactions:

  - Timestamp of transaction
  - Transaction id (int)
  - Id of executed order (int)
  - Price and volume executed
- Get open orders. Returns the current active orders on the exchange.

  - Timestamp of order entry
  - Order id (int)
  - Price and volume of order

Note that:
  - New order requests can be sent to server and instantly be matched, and as a result never show up in a getOpenOrders call but only as a completed transaction.
  - The allowed REST call frequency is limited so I need to make sure to catch everything that happens between the calls.

How do I code this in an efficient, fail safe way?

Comment: A simple answer will do:-)

Comment: Yeah I guess that's a better idea

Comment: does the exchange offer a REST call which takes in the timestamp as the parameter and returns the order ids and state(executed,changed e.t.c) since that time stamp ? It can make your code more efficient if something like this is available.

Comment: No, the openOrders call returns all orders that are active on the exchanged (i.e unfilled and partially filled). The getTransactions call returns all executed trades, and this list can be limited by number of transactions to be returned.

Comment: Is this a public API? I am looking for something like this, can you send a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. write a Async rest client based on [See Listing 17 in this web page] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jaxrs20-1929352.html.
2. Invoke the Get transactions and Get Orders by passing the corresponding call back handlers to process the response.
3. schedule the above rest calls
4. The callback handler then handles the response from exchange and updates your local cache (or database) accordingly.
5. The callback handler will in turn aggregates a FIX engine that converts the data from exchange to your 'Order' entity.

I hope you will save the order id and other details to the database anyway. So when you get the response back you can process the details easily.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However I am more interested in how the system would handle the response from the rest calls, to make sure no information that happens between the rest calls gets lost.

Comment: @user3607022 sorry I am not sure how we miss responses from rest calls when we use a call back to handle the response. Your asynchronous call will then delegates the response to the callback handler. Please ignore me if I am not clear about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for Data synchronization design patterns. Considering your scenario, the solution depends on whether "Exchange" is willing to build more features. My best bet would to build a audit log in Exchange which captures every data change (add/update/delete). Also Exchange must expose a REST API to pull the audit logs. Your application can then rely on this API.

Your specific requirement "New order requests can be sent to server and instantly be matched, and as a result never show up in a getOpenOrders call but only as a completed transaction." makes it necessary that Exchange should implement flexible API, so that the synchronization is perfect.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However I don't think the exchange is willing to change their API, and also I believe it's possible to design some kind of algorithm that makes sure sync is perfect (ecept for what might happen after our system's last REST call).